# Storing Webcam Image

Tags: php, webcam.js

I have this code to capture an image from the webcam, and I need to store it in a directory on my laptop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Capture webcam image with php and jquery - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.25/webcam.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #results { padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Capture webcam image with php and jquery - ItSolutionStuff.com</h1>
   
    <form method="POST" action="storeImage.php">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="my_camera"></div>
                <br/>
                <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
                <input type="hidden" name="image" class="image-tag">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
  
<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 490,
        height: 390,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
  
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
  
    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            $(".image-tag").val(data_uri);
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

This is the index.php file, and the next one is the php file to save image.

```html
<?php
    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $folderPath = "upload/";
  
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';
  
    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
  
    print_r($fileName);
  
?>
```

I have also created the 'upload' folder, but the image is still not getting saved.

I've made a folder names 'webcam' on my desktop, inside that folder are these two files, and the other folder named 'upload'.

How do i get the image to save in that folder?

Comment: Please do some debugging to find out where it goes wrong. Have you checked what `$_POST['image']` contains? Do you have write access in that folder? Have you checked that you get the correct values after your explodes?

Comment: _Side note:_ you configure the camera to deliver jpeg but you're saving the file as png.

Comment: Yes i have access to write in the file. $_POST['image'] contains the image captured from the webcam, is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: I changed it to jpeg, still the same error.

Comment: Have you checked your servers error log to see if you get any error messages? Also, do a `var_dump()` on all the variables to see if they contain what you expect.

Comment: also your folderPath needs to be an absolute path.

Comment: Okay I got the solution! Thank You both for your inputs!